# Removing items from Hashtable in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, collections, hashtable

Is there a better way to remove multiple items from a hash table based on a condition, other than saving the keys first in a list and then iterating through that and removing each item one by one? the Generic list provides a "RemoveAll" method to which I can pass an anonymous function, but it seems there isn't an equivalent approach for HashTable. note: I am using .NET framework 2.0

Comment: have you tried hashtable.Remove method

Comment: Is it multi-threaded application?

Comment: it is not multi-threaded and hashtable.remove method can be used, but I need to loop twice, once to find the keys to be removed and then loop through the keys collection once again to remove each one separately (there is nothing like removeRange method where in I can pass an array of keys)

Comment: No, there's no equivalent.  And Remove() invalidates the enumerator, so really what you are doing is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your application.  If your application is multi-threaded and **pre** .NET 4.0, it's usually better to use a `ReaderWriterLock/ReaderWriterLockSlim` and get a reader lock, build a list of the keys you want to remove, then upgrade to a write lock, and perform a loop on the list to remove the keys.  This way, while you are iterating over the `Hashtable` for keys to remove, other readers can access it without being locked out.

Now if you can get to .NET 4.0, The `ConcurrentDictionary` is brilliant and has much less contention!  If you stay in .NET 2.0, I'd recommend `Dictionary` even though it's not part of your question per se.

**UPDATE** If your application is **not** multi-threaded, no need to lock, but you still need to build the list of keys, because calling Remove() while iterating invalidates the enumerator.  So basically, you're doing it correctly given your comment to the question.

Comment: thanks, I am working on legacy code. do you mean I have to covert the hashtable into a dictionary? even then how will it solve this problem? does it have better API to manipulate the collection?

Comment: @RKP: No, just microsoft recommendations to always prefer the generic collections to the original collections.  More performant, non-boxing, etc.  But, if it's legacy code, you just have to use what you're dealt :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. What's wrong with just iterating through your list and removing the keys that way anyway? If you have to do it often, just make it a function...

If you were using .NET framework 3.5 or higher, LINQ would probably make your goal much easier to accomplish.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, LINQ doesn't provide mutating operations on sequences (i.e. no adds, removes, etc).

Comment: Right, but you could create a copy of the sequence where elements only match (a) condition(s).

Comment: True, though in essence you're still making a sequence of results to remove.  Simplifies the query process, but the 1) make list 2) remove all keys one-by-one from list - still same algorithm.  That was the main point.  I agree the LINQ query is easier for making the list though.